Visual Studio Code was blocked from use because it is not from an identified developer
I'm new to Mac and would like to know if this occurrence is normal,
I installed the Visual Studio code (exactly version 1.91 from the official site) by downloading the file and then inserting it into the "applications" folder. I can open it without problems and make it work, the system does not block it in any way, but if I go to the security settings of the Mac I get the message telling me that the visual studio code is a program that comes from an unidentified developer and asks me for permission, does this happen to you too?
I proceed to do the steps

I downloaded it from here (https://code.visualstudio.com/)
The file I download is a zip version.
Once the download is finished it seems to extract the internal file by itself and leaves that file inside the download folder and puts the zip version in the trash

At this point I put that file in the application folder
I press it but it gives me the error that it was not downloaded from the Apple store
I go to settings to change the setting for starting programs even taken from the internet and it writes this to me


I have a Macbook pro M2 chip
Can someone explain why am I getting this message?

From where, exactly, did you download VS Code?  Because the binary on my system validates.  $ spctl -a -vvv -t execute Visual\ Studio\ Code.app Visual Studio Code.app: accepted source=Notarized Developer ID origin=Developer ID Application: Microsoft Corporation (UBF8T346G9)

I just grabbed the current .zip download for both ARM and Intel, and they are both notarized with Microsoft listed as the developer.

Are you running Little Snitch or something else that would be blocking macOS trying to verify the notarization?

@MarcWilson Absolutely not, I'm not using Little Snitch.
But I found a way where the message is not displayed.
I disabled Safari's automatic extraction, then I redownloaded it and manually extracted the file and placed it in the applications folder, at this point I started the program and that message doesn't appear. I still don't understand why it appears if I don't do it this way

The automatic extraction is a bad idea anyway, leave it off.  But as far as what's happening to the binary, some extended attribute is probably being applied to it.  Add to your question the result of xattr -l nameofvscode.app after Safari extracts it.
